# Transform latitude and longitude to Transverse Mercator

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, wgs84, proj, transverse-mercator

I would like to transform point in WGS84 lat lon to Transverse Mercator:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=114 +k=1 +x_0=-49099.65399999998 +y_0=-2544749.4072 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

I could easily do it with PROJ library but I'm in a situation where I need to implement in 'C' by myself. I found this [guide](https://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-services/coordinate-conversion/projection-conversions/transverse-mercator-transformation-formulae#lbl2) on the formula, and coded accordingly:

```
UTM LatLongToUTM(LatLong ll) {

    double lat = ll.latitude;
    double lon = ll.longitude;

    double lat_r = lat * M_PI / 180.0;
    double lon_r = lon * M_PI / 180.0;

    double lat_0 = 0.0; // lat of the projection center
    double lon_0 = 114.0; // lon of the projection center
    double x_0 = -49099.65399999998; // False easting
    double y_0 = -2544749.4072; // False northing
    double k_0 = 1; // Scale factor. Determines scale factor used in the projection. Scale on the central meridian.

    double f = 1.0 / 298.257223563; // Flattening
    double a = 6378137.0; // Semi-major axis = equatorial radius
    double b = a * (1.0 - f);
    double e_2 = 2*f - f*f;
    double e_4 = e_2 * e_2;
    double e_6 = e_2 * e_2 * e_2;

    double A_0 = 1.0 - (e_2 / 4.0) - (3 * e_4 / 64.0) - (5 * e_6 / 256.0);
    double A_2 = 3.0 * (e_2 + e_4 / 4.0 + 15 * e_6 / 128.0) / 8.0;
    double A_4 = 15.0 * (e_4 + 3 * e_6 / 4.0) / 256.0;
    double A_6 = 35.0 * e_6 / 3072.0;

    double m = a * (A_0 * lat - A_2 * sin(2 * lat_r) + A_4 * sin(4 * lat_r) - A_6 * sin(6 * lat_r));
    double m_0 = 0.0;

    double rho = a * (1.0 - e_2) / pow(1.0 - e_2 * sin(lat_r) * sin(lat_r), 1.5);
    double v = a / sqrt(1 - e_2 * sin(lat_r) * sin(lat_r));
    double psi = v / rho;
    double psi_2 = psi * psi;
    double psi_3 = psi * psi * psi;
    double psi_4 = psi_2 * psi_2;
    double t = tan(lat_r);
    double t_2 = t * t;
    double t_4 = t_2 * t_2;
    double t_6 = t_2 * t_2 * t_2;
    double w = lon - lon_0;
    double w_2 = w * w;
    double w_4 = w_2 * w_2;
    double w_6 = w_2 * w_2 * w_2;
    double w_8 = w_4 * w_4;

    UTM utm;

    double nterm_1 = w_2 * v * sin(lat_r) * cos(lat_r) / 2.0;
    double nterm_2 = w_4 * v * sin(lat_r) * pow(cos(lat_r), 3) * (4.0 * psi_2 + psi - t_2) / 24.0;
    double nterm_3 = w_6 * v * sin(lat_r) * pow(cos(lat_r), 5) * (8.0 * psi_4 * (11.0 - 24.0 * t_2) - 28.0 * psi_3 * (1.0 - 6.0 * t_2) + psi_2 * (1.0 - 32.0 * t_2) - psi * (2.0 * t_2) + t_4) / 720.0;
    double nterm_4 = w_8 * v * sin(lat_r) * pow(cos(lat_r), 7) * (1385.0 - 3111.0 * t_2 + 543.0 * t_4 - t_6) / 40320.0;

    utm.y = y_0 + k_0 * (m - m_0 + nterm_1 + nterm_2 + nterm_3 + nterm_4);

    double eterm_1 = w_2 * cos(lat_r) * cos(lat_r) * (psi - t_2) / 6.0;
    double eterm_2 = w_4 * pow(cos(lat_r), 4) * (4.0 * psi_3 * (1.0 - 6.0 * t_2) + psi_2 * (1.0 + 8.0 * t_2) - psi * 2.0 * t_2 + t_4) / 120.0;
    double eterm_3 = w_6 * pow(cos(lat_r), 6) * (61.0 - 479.0 * t_2 + 179.0 * t_4 - t_6)/ 5040.0;

    utm.x = x_0 + k_0 * v * w * cos(lat_r) * (1.0 + eterm_1 + eterm_2 + eterm_3);

    return utm;
}
```

But the test result is not correct.

```
23.001868 114.479211
==> 2842682.03  144192843.29 // should be 30.00 75.33
```

What did I do wrong? (Please ignore the utm varible as it is not utm actually)

Comment: don't reimplement projection (again) - just use an available library

Comment: @IanTurton Unfortunately I cannot find any available library for my platform. PROJ 5 is pure C but has too many dynamic memory allocations which my platform does not support.